# Visualforce Page: How to display all the content/data in a single VF PDF page

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf

I am trying a display a content/data in a pdf in VF page rendered as PDF, but in pdf the content is splitting into multiple pages which I dont want, is there a way we can try displaying everything in a single page.
I tried using page-break-inside: avoid; in div, but it did not work.

Here is the below code:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    
   <style>
        @page {
            size: auto; 
            margin: 0; 
        }

        body {
            margin: 0; 
        }

        div {
            page-break-inside: avoid; 
        }
    </style>

<!--content----------------------------------->
        <div>
               
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut ipsum at arcu interdum fringilla vitae at neque. Ut et tortor facilisis, elementum tortor vel, faucibus sapien. Proin consectetur efficitur orci at placerat. Aenean consequat massa et turpis tempus, nec pulvinar sem ultricies. Quisque sed aliquet elit. Mauris facilisis quam id laoreet faucibus. Nunc placerat iaculis quam. Sed mattis dolor ac cursus vestibulum. Aliquam dignissim a magna vitae facilisis.</p>
            <p>Nullam cursus, nisi at finibus tristique, nibh augue ultricies tortor, ac auctor neque justo vel mauris. Aliquam porttitor, mi et luctus efficitur, ipsum lacus elementum enim, sit amet tristique tortor nunc eu odio. Integer hendrerit felis turpis, et feugiat elit pellentesque sed. Etiam sit amet consequat felis. Duis sagittis dolor a velit gravida tristique. Sed lacinia turpis ac nulla volutpat, vitae gravida sem interdum. Nullam ultrices eu elit sit amet efficitur. Proin facilisis, est non malesuada placerat, purus elit cursus neque, vitae tincidunt ex ligula eget felis.</p>
            <p>Donec et lacinia mi, at faucibus nunc. Nullam eu orci ut est dapibus eleifend. Quisque vitae est sed urna vulputate hendrerit. Donec interdum risus ligula, at fermentum urna venenatis sed. Nam tincidunt dolor sit amet luctus rutrum. Nulla rhoncus, nunc at fringilla cursus, est arcu fermentum tortor, et placerat mauris tortor in sem. Aenean id ante vitae dui cursus lobortis in ac mi. Donec facilisis tincidunt dui, et placerat urna rutrum et.</p>
            <p>Phasellus posuere felis eget tristique posuere. Sed fermentum ultrices massa, nec convallis nisi venenatis vitae. Vestibulum convallis lectus eu pharetra auctor. Fusce pharetra purus eget erat efficitur, ac lobortis nisi ultricies. Praesent eget iaculis sapien, sed lobortis nisi. Integer accumsan ultrices dui, in laoreet est consequat nec. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sollicitudin leo ac arcuUnfortunately, the response was truncated. Here's the continuation of the example code:</p>


            <p>Phasellus posuere felis eget tristique posuere. Sed fermentum ultrices massa, nec convallis nisi venenatis vitae. Vestibulum convallis lectus eu pharetra auctor. Fusce pharetra purus eget erat efficitur, ac lobortis nisi ultricies. Praesent eget iaculis sapien, sed lobortis nisi. Integer accumsan ultrices dui, in laoreet est consequat nec. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sollicitudin leo ac arcu aliquet, et malesuada enim euismod. In eget fermentum lacus. Pellentesque vel interdum arcu. Donec ac leo ullamcorper, cursus mauris ac, lacinia tellus. Mauris ut lectus ut ante lobortis convallis a ut mauris. Suspendisse potenti. Integer suscipit turpis non justo consequat interdum. Nulla facilisi.</p>
            
            
             
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut ipsum at arcu interdum fringilla vitae at neque. Ut et tortor facilisis, elementum tortor vel, faucibus sapien. Proin consectetur efficitur orci at placerat. Aenean consequat massa et turpis tempus, nec pulvinar sem ultricies. Quisque sed aliquet elit. Mauris facilisis quam id laoreet faucibus. Nunc placerat iaculis quam. Sed mattis dolor ac cursus vestibulum. Aliquam dignissim a magna vitae facilisis.</p>
            <p>Nullam cursus, nisi at finibus tristique, nibh augue ultricies tortor, ac auctor neque justo vel mauris. Aliquam porttitor, mi et luctus efficitur, ipsum lacus elementum enim, sit amet tristique tortor nunc eu odio. Integer hendrerit felis turpis, et feugiat elit pellentesque sed. Etiam sit amet consequat felis. Duis sagittis dolor a velit gravida tristique. Sed lacinia turpis ac nulla volutpat, vitae gravida sem interdum. Nullam ultrices eu elit sit amet efficitur. Proin facilisis, est non malesuada placerat, purus elit cursus neque, vitae tincidunt ex ligula eget felis.</p>
            <p>Donec et lacinia mi, at faucibus nunc. Nullam eu orci ut est dapibus eleifend. Quisque vitae est sed urna vulputate hendrerit. Donec interdum risus ligula, at fermentum urna venenatis sed. Nam tincidunt dolor sit amet luctus rutrum. Nulla rhoncus, nunc at fringilla cursus, est arcu fermentum tortor, et placerat mauris tortor in sem. Aenean id ante vitae dui cursus lobortis in ac mi. Donec facilisis tincidunt dui, et placerat urna rutrum et.</p>
            <p>Phasellus posuere felis eget tristique posuere. Sed fermentum ultrices massa, nec convallis nisi venenatis vitae. Vestibulum convallis lectus eu pharetra auctor. Fusce pharetra purus eget erat efficitur, ac lobortis nisi ultricies. Praesent eget iaculis sapien, sed lobortis nisi. Integer accumsan ultrices dui, in laoreet est consequat nec. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sollicitudin leo ac arcuUnfortunately, the response was truncated. Here's the continuation of the example code:</p>


            <p>Phasellus posuere felis eget tristique posuere. Sed fermentum ultrices massa, nec convallis nisi venenatis vitae. Vestibulum convallis lectus eu pharetra auctor. Fusce pharetra purus eget erat efficitur, ac lobortis nisi ultricies. Praesent eget iaculis sapien, sed lobortis nisi. Integer accumsan ultrices dui, in laoreet est consequat nec. Suspendisse potenti. Sed sollicitudin leo ac arcu aliquet, et malesuada enim euismod. In eget fermentum lacus. Pellentesque vel interdum arcu. Donec ac leo ullamcorper, cursus mauris ac, lacinia tellus. Mauris ut lectus ut ante lobortis convallis a ut mauris. Suspendisse potenti. Integer suscipit turpis non justo consequat interdum. Nulla facilisi.</p>
            
        </div>
    

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Use a smaller font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can force it to just a single page.

However, you can define a custom page size - and make it big enough that you never get a page break.

Something like this:

```
@page {  size: 8.5in 50in; }
```

Flying Saucer Spec (which is what VF PDF generation uses) is [here](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_34)

Comment: Am working on some PDF output right now and can confirm that this approach works. Removing `@page` does not work - looks like that defaults to letter size.